# Диорама о захвате партизанами склада с боеприпасами....Верно ли построение с предлогом «о»?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Диорама о захвате партизанами склада с боеприпасами...* Верно ли построение с предлогом «о»? Диорама о чем-то или диорама чего?

Comment: Диорама, рассказывающая...  Диорама «Операция СКЛАД»...

Comment: в качестве заголовка...рассказывающая...это слишком большой заголовок...

Comment: Схему с заголовком и подзаголовком можно применить.

Answer (score 1):

Диорама - это всё-таки картина, хоть и полукругом. Можем мы сказать "Картина о 9 вале"? Вряд ли. Нужно название.

А почему нельзя написать «диорама "Захват склада с боеприпасами"»? Если это не заголовок, а просто в тексте, то так: Диорама, представляющая захват партизанами склада с боеприпасами.

Comment: ну как я сама лично могу озаглавить название диорамы...в Сети названия нигде нет...

Comment: Смотря каков контекст. Может, вам и не нужно вообще название. Вот в этом тексте нет названия, но всё понятно: "...совсем необычное дело - батальная диорама в сельском музее. На диораме скрупулезно воссоздан наиболее яркий эпизод военных событий в селе - захват партизанами склада боеприпасов румынской дивизии. https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/4768613/post363216967/  Вам тоже можно сказать: "Батальная диорама, воссоздающая захват партизанами склада боеприпасов румынской дивизии "
Или ещё проще: "Батальная диорама в селе таком-то", там ведь других диорам не было, только эта.

Comment: в статье перечисляются разные военные картины...что к чему (каждое название картины - подзаголовки жирные)...и есть эта диорама....

Comment: Ну, так и сказать: батальная диорама в  музее села Ароматного .